# Возвращение String из функции

Tags: android

Написал функцию, в ней идёт присвоение значения к `String`, но как вернуть значение из этого `String`?

```
public void EtChanger(String Edittext, String ColIndex, String SMSColIndex, String SMSString, String SerialNumber) {
    Log.d(TAG, Edittext+" "+ColIndex);
    if (ColIndex.equals(Edittext)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ColIndex = EditText");
        Log.d(TAG, "SMS ColIndex = "+SMSColIndex);
        if (SMSColIndex.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SMS ColIndex Is Empty");
            SMSString = "";
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "SMS ColIndex isn`t empty");
            SMSString = SMSColIndex;
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"ColIndex != EditText" );
        SMSString = SerialNumber + Edittext;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "В итоге SMS String = "+SMSString);
}
```

Вызов функции в программе:

```
//---MoneyNumb---
EtChanger(moneynumb.getText().toString(), s.getString(moneynumbColIndex), ss.getString(moneynumbSMSColIndex), moneynubs, "%12");
Log.d(TAG, "MoneyNumberS = "+moneynubs);
```

Логи(ничего не изменяется):

`03-17 06:05:43.879 4156-4156/com.example.examples.easygsm D/myLogs: ColIndex = EditText
03-17 06:05:43.879 4156-4156/com.example.examples.easygsm D/myLogs: SMS ColIndex = 
03-17 06:05:43.879 4156-4156/com.example.examples.easygsm D/myLogs: SMS ColIndex Is Empty
03-17 06:05:43.879 4156-4156/com.example.examples.easygsm D/myLogs: В итоге SMS String = 
03-17 06:05:43.879 4156-4156/com.example.examples.easygsm D/myLogs: MoneyNumberS =`

После изменения EditText:

`03-17 06:06:06.643 4156-4156/com.example.examples.easygsm D/myLogs: ColIndex != EditText
03-17 06:06:06.643 4156-4156/com.example.examples.easygsm D/myLogs: В итоге SMS String = %12*121#
03-17 06:06:06.643 4156-4156/com.example.examples.easygsm D/myLogs: MoneyNumberS =`

Comment: Наверное вот так: `public String EtChanger(....){..... return SMSString;}`

Comment: `moneynubs` глобальная переменная?

Comment: @LamerXaKer, да. Пишу отдельно функцию, т.к. она будет применяться к 20-ти `EditText`ам (Это я про EtChanger)

Comment: ну тогда напишите `moneynubs = SMSString;` после `Log.d(TAG, "В итоге SMS String = "+SMSString);` а функцию оставьте как и была `void`

Comment: @LamerXaKer, не выйдет так, т.к. для другого `EditText`-a не будет работать, т.к. `moneynubs` - это для `EditText`-a с названием `money numbers`, для `EditText`-a с названием `CallTimes` - будет `calltimess`, для этого и было введено `SMSString` по сути `SMSString `- это `calltimess`, `moneynumbs` и т.д.

Comment: ну, тогда функцию из `void` в `String`, в конце `return SMSString;` и вызов `moneynubs = EtChanger(moneynumb.getText().toString(), s.getString(moneynumbColIndex), ss.getString(moneynumbSMSColIndex), moneynubs, "%12");` ну и соответственно дальше в других эдитах `calltimess = EtChanger(....)`

Comment: @LamerXaKer, спасибо, так и сделал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String EtChanger(...
    ...
    return yourString;
}
```

Для возврата строки методом.

В вызове функции:

```
moneynubs = EtChanger();
```